# Record video, with audio from a separate microphone on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, audio-recording

I have a logitech camera, and a pair of [in-ear microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GAW69M). All of them are connected to a windows 7 computer (camera through USB, microphone through the input jack 3.5mm).

Which software would allow me to record the video, along with the in-ear microphone?

Answer (score 1):

What you would need is a program that can take separate video and audio tracks. You can either capture them separately with different programs or together with a single program. Each has their merits. [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) is a free Open Source option that will capture them together. It has a few nice benefits to it as well.

- Encoding using H264 (x264) and AAC.
- Support for Intel Quick Sync Video (QSV) and NVENC.
- Unlimited number of scenes and sources.
- Live RTMP streaming to Twitch, YouTube, DailyMotion, Hitbox and more.
- File output to MP4 or FLV.
- GPU-based game capture for high performance game streaming.
- DirectShow capture device support (webcams, capture cards, etc).
- Windows 8 high speed monitor capture support.
- Bilinear or lanczos3 resampling.